# How to pass $event from custom directive to function?

Tags: angularjs

This is some directive that i use for detecting enter key

```
.directive('enterSubmit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
        var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
        if (code === 13) {
          if (!event.shiftKey) {
            event.preventDefault();
            scope.$apply(attrs.enterSubmit);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

I have a `function` that i wanna get `$event` as a parameter to it.

```
$scope.test = function(evt){
   var el = angular.element(evt.target);
   console.log(el[0]);
}
```

But when i use $event as i could in built-in directives

```
<textarea enter-submit="test($event)"></textarea>
```

It says `evt is undefined` so how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your if to this:

```
if (!event.shiftKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var enterSubmitFunction = $parse(attrs['enterSubmit']);                                 
    enterSubmitFunction(scope, { $event: event });
    scope.$apply();
}
```

You'll need to inject `$parse` now, and i'm not sure if you need to use `scope.$parent` in the `enterSubmitFunction` or just `scope`. Try both.

Comment: Thanks and `$parse(attr['enterSubmit'])` should be `$parse(attrs['enterSubmit'])`

Comment: Yep, just edited it to reflect that, was too used to use attr for myself :)

Comment: I need this solution too.  You probably saved me at least 20 minutes digging through the documentation!